# how to display custom product taxonomy in admin order detail?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom taxonomy for woocommerce products like seasons. I'd like to display what season of product is placed in the admin order detail.

Comment: Add some codes that you have tried, otherwise the question does not follow the community guideline

Comment: Here is a good starting point with a lot of examples - https://www.ibenic.com/manage-order-item-meta-woocommerce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this add the following lines of code at the end of your theme’s functions.php file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta','woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta',10,3);
    
     
    
    function woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta($item_id, $item, $product){
    
       echo '<p>'.get_the_term_list($product->id, 'product_cat').'</p>';
    
    }
```

Save the file by clicking on update file button after placing the above code.

Now if you move to an order from backend again you’ll see category name listed under products in order.

Comment: That shows product category. I want to see custom taxonomy instead.

Comment: My mistake. It works! Thank you